# BIRT Cross-tab borders around column group levels

Tags: birt

I feel like I'm missing something really simple but I can't for the life of me figure out what. I have a pretty simple cross-tab that pulls stock figures for parts. The stock figures are being grouped by a warehouse set, then the warehouse, then stock status

Trying to put a border or set of borders around the group stages that filters down so that it's easy to see where the different groups start and end. Ideally I'm looking at doing a combination of black border around the main group and a silver border around the subgroups/measures. Does that make sense and is it possible? Something like this:

(imagine | is black and : is silver)

```
Set group  |                     SET A                       |
WH group   |     WH A      :      WH B     :       WH C      |
Part No    | PHYS  : QUAR  : PHYS  : QUAR  :   PHYS  : QUAR  |
part a     |  5    :   2   :  10   :   0   :   25    :  55   |
part b     |  0    :   12  :  155  :  26   :   5000  :  250  |
```

The problem that I'm having is basically how can I determine when I would put a silver border or a black border for each different group level? Set group is easy enough as that's a simple black border left/right, but for the WH group and the status group under it I need to be able to determine which column is the first in each group and apply a black border left, which is the last in the group and black border right, everything in between would be silver

Same for the actual measures, can I determine same first/last measure based on the Set group and apply the same border constraints?

I keep trying to play with just straight border styles on different cells in the cross tab but I can't get the output above

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help for cross tabs, because I avoid using them.
Instead I am using ordinary table items and a little SQL magic based on analytic functions and case-expressions like this (the example is from https://modern-sql.com/de/anwendung/pivot in German language):

```
SELECT year
     , SUM(CASE WHEN month =  1 THEN revenue END) rev01
     , SUM(CASE WHEN month =  2 THEN revenue END) rev01
       ...
     , SUM(CASE WHEN month = 12 THEN revenue END) rev12
  FROM (SELECT invoices.*
             , EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM invoice_date) year
             , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM invoice_date) month
          FROM invoices 
       ) invoices
 GROUP BY year
```

The same principle can be used to get the column header values.

For a table, one can use the `onCreate` event to loop through the columns and dynamically adjust their left and right borders (width, color etc).

```
// Untested!
for (var colno=0; colno<this.getColumnCount(); colno++) {
    var col = this.getColumn(col);
    var style = col.getStyle();
    if (columnBelongsToNext(col-1)) {
        style.borderLeftWidth = "0";
    } else {
        style.borderLeftWidth = "2px";
    }
    if (columnBelongsToNext(col)) {
        style.borderRightWidth = "0";
    } else {
        style.borderRightWidth = "2px";
    }
}
```

Here it is very important to set the borderLeftXXX attribute of the *i+1*th column to the same value as the borderRightXXX attribute of the *i*th column.
Otherwise the computed values might contradict each other.